# change url structure manual on .htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have a https://example.com/page/?id=123 this type of url and i wont a rule for change this url to https://example.com/page/123/

i have this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

No need to change the pages URL with .htaccess

**Step 1** log into your admin end then go to setting

**Step 2** there will be a menu with name permalink

**Step 3** click on it and tick the radio button with name post name check image

http://prntscr.com/fh9ry8

the URL will change automatically as you require